# Find the slope of QQ-plot in R?

Tags: r, plot

I drew the QQ-plot to test whether the data comes from an exponential distribution.

How can I find the slope of QQ-plot?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to know the answer to your own question? Why do you want the slope? Under what conditions is a qq plot linear (excluding the case where the slope is 1 because the distributions are identical)?